# xfce4-terminal not showing colors properly on zsh theme prompt

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, zsh, xfce4-terminal

I use zsh with `oh-my-zsh` and `xfce4-terminal` in XUbuntu 14.04.

If I configure xfce-terminal with `xterm-256color`, like this:

[image: xfce4-terminal xterm-256color]

I get this error:

`*** VTE ***: Failed to load terminal capabilities from '/etc/termcap'`

If I leave the default setting, my terminal has 8 colors:

```
$ echotc Co 
8

$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

If I export, like this:

```
$ export TERM=xterm-256color
```

I get proper values and it seems that I have truly 256 colors:

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color

$ echotc Co
256
```

But my `zsh` prompt doesn't show proper colors. For instance with `agnoster` theme:

[image: xfce4-terminal]

I see proper colors in the output commands, but only 8 colors in the `zsh` prompt.

But using `terminator` I see all correct with `xterm-256color`:

[image: terminator-256]

The most funny part, is that `terminator` with only 8 colors, shows theme properly:

[image: terminator-8]

**What I need to configure to continue using `xfce4-terminal` with 256 colors and proper theme colors?**

Comment: That script uses ANSI escape sequences though. That means that the terminal *does* support 256 colors, however  Zsh doesn't render colors using those escape sequences AFAIK. Note also that in Terminator the time on the left side of the prompt is not shown. It might just be that the colors are rendered slightly differently in `xfce-terminal` and Terminator, enough to hide the dark grey on `xfce-terminal` and the light grey on Terminator. Try to change the background color to something totally different (try e.g. red). Can you see the full prompt in both `xfce-terminal` and Terminator that way?

Comment: @Terrance with Tango I see better prompt. so strange... but it is not like in `terminator`. I like how it gets with "Solarized (dark)" colors preset.

Comment: @Terrance horrible results and less pretty colors...

Comment: @Terrance the issue is in the zsh prompt colors not in the terminal itself

Comment: Fair enough.  Just another thought, what if you add `export TERM=xterm-256color` to the `~/.zshrc` file so it loads when you launch the xfce-terminal?

Comment: @Terrance look at my screenshots, this var is printed each time. it doesn't matter where it is, in the zshrc or in the actual terminal session.

Comment: Adding the `export TERM=xterm-256color` to the zshrc was to defeat the error of `*** VTE ***: Failed to load terminal capabilities from '/etc/termcap'`.  I have seen themes change the colors of the fonts and backgrounds in the xfce-terminal, but others it does not like in the gnome-terminal or terminator like you have tried.   I am agreeing with kos comment to try different background colors.  What may look right to me can look completely different to someone else.  So, for mine I had to keep playing with the colors themselves till I got mine the way I like it.

Comment: @Terrance yes, it seems the behaviour changes depending on the theme. but, does it make sense? why I need to change my theme to get proper colors in zsh prompt?

Comment: zsh is only a shell, like bash, csh, ksh etc.  `xfce-terminal` is only a terminal application that shows you the shell.  Each `terminal` changes the colors that are used per `terminal` application.  [Here is a snapshot](http://i.imgur.com/jriMSAG.jpg) where I put 3 different terminals, all with the `xterm-256color` set on each of them, and as you can see they are all different.  It all depends on the terminal you are using and less on the shell.  The left is `gnome-terminal`, the middle is `rxvt-unicode` and the right is `xfce-terminal`.  In my opinion `rxvt` looks the best.

Comment: @Terrance the question is: why `zsh` prompt is not using 256 colors in some themes of `xfce4-terminal`?

Comment: Because themes affect the Palette in `xfce-terminal` differently than other terminals.  You can always change the colors of your Palette after you select your theme.  You must change them color by color, but you can change them.   When you select a Preset in the colors of the Preferences, you can select any of the colors above and change them to your liking.